# Simple Mandala Generator JS

Tags: javascript, html

for a univerity Project i need to do a simple Mandala Generator.
I want to use this example http://jsfiddle.net/66ywh9f4/

This is the Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    Points: <input type='range' min='3' max='40' id='points' value='13' /><br />
    <canvas id='canvas' width='400' height='400' />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and js

```
   var points = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= point_count; i++) {
        angle = i * 2 * Math.PI / point_count - Math.PI / 2;
        points.push({
            'x': radius + radius * Math.cos(angle),
            'y': radius + radius * Math.sin(angle)
        })
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
            ctx.moveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
            ctx.lineTo(points[j].x, points[j].y);
        }
    }
    ctx.stroke();
**}**

function draw() {
    drawShape(contx, document.getElementById('points').value, canv.width / 2);
}
draw();
```

But when i run it it shows: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } at line 19

Comment: You have extra } brace after ctx.stroke();

Comment: The linked jsfiddle does not have the syntax error in the above code (`**}**`) and also works perfectly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "fix my homework" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you have to implement it if you do not want another function call. I have changed the fiddle according to your answer.

```js
var canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
var contx = canv.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
    var ctx = contx;
    var point_count = document.getElementById('points').value;
    var radius = canv.width / 2;
     var points = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= point_count; i++) {
        angle = i * 2 * Math.PI / point_count - Math.PI / 2;
        points.push({
            'x': radius + radius * Math.cos(angle),
            'y': radius + radius * Math.sin(angle)
        });
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
            ctx.moveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
            ctx.lineTo(points[j].x, points[j].y);
        }
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
draw();
document.getElementById('points').oninput = draw;
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    Points: <input type='range' min='3' max='40' id='points' value='13' /><br />
    <canvas id='canvas' width='400' height='400' />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You have extra } brace after ctx.stroke(); And you are missing contx and funcs necessary to make it work.

```
  var points = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= point_count; i++) {
        angle = i * 2 * Math.PI / point_count - Math.PI / 2;
        points.push({
            'x': radius + radius * Math.cos(angle),
            'y': radius + radius * Math.sin(angle)
        })
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
            ctx.moveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
            ctx.lineTo(points[j].x, points[j].y);
        }
    }
    ctx.stroke();

//} <-REMOVE THIS

    function draw() {
//      THIS WONT WORK IT DOESN'T EXISTS ->  drawShape(contx, document.getElementById('points').value, canv.width / 2);
    }
    draw();
```

Comment: ty, but now i have "Unexpected end of input at line 29"

Comment: @AlessaKlinger Check my answer now. You removed the original function and you were trying to send contx in a function which doesn't exist

Comment: @AlessaKlinger You are welcome, Don't forget to up-vote my answer :) TY